# price is not changing it's content on page (sorry guys it was a css problem tried to delete post but couldn't)

Tags: javascript

```
const axios = require('axios');  
getprice = async () => {
let nsdq = await axios.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=e");  
console.log(nsdq)
let share = nsdq.data['Global Quote']['01. symbol'] //ur infomartion
console.log(nsdq.data)

console.log(share)
price = document.querySelector('.nasdaqPrice')
price.innerText = String(share)  
}  
getprice()
```

`this is share price which is IBM which is a string`
i am also using browserify and if i change price.innertext = 'hi' it appears on the page

Comment: what is the problem here can you explain ? code is working just as it is whats your expected result is ?

Comment: IBM is not being shown on the page but if i do price.innerText = 'heoeoaoeao' it is shown

Comment: though i am not familiar with axios library but i would suggest to console log `nsdq` and see is it returning promise or final result

Comment: can you share screenshot of your console ?

Comment: ok do you have discord i am not sure how to send screenshot on stackoverflow

Comment: i have posted a code correction kindly check and reply is it fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Are your console logs showing any information?

I think you need to define getPrice, maybe like `const getprice = async () => {...}`

Comment: console.log(share) is showing IBM

Comment: i think final result not sure because i'm able to access nsdq.data

Answer (score 0):

ok i got your problem you have to pass responseType in second argument as config in you axios request so you will get json data in reponse

try you code this way

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getprice = async () => {
    let nsdq = await axios.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=e", {
        responseType: "json"
    });
    let share = nsdq.data['Global Quote']['01. symbol'] //ur infomartion
    price = document.querySelector('.nasdaqPrice')
    price.innerText = String(share)
}
getprice()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only errors i get when i was testing your code is **`getprice` and `price` is not defined !**

When I put a `let` before `getPrice` and `price` when you declared them, all the error vanished and **IBM** displayed on the element selected.

Here is my code :-

```
const axios = require('axios');
let getprice = async () => {
    let nsdq = await axios.get(
        "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=e"
    );
    console.log(nsdq);
    let share = nsdq.data["Global Quote"]["01. symbol"]; //ur infomartion
    console.log(nsdq.data);

    console.log(share);
    let price = document.querySelector("#view");
    price.innerText = String(share);
};
getprice();
```

Here is the screenShot.
[image: IBM rendered !]